# App Center test cases getting failed throwing error "shel': Error while starting {"message"=>"Waited for Calabash server on 37282. Did not launch.","

Tags: calabash, visual-studio-app-center, xamarin.uitest

I am using Xamarin UITest 2.2.6 (Tried downgrading the version to 2.2.4 & 2.2.5).

I can sucessfully run my tests on my local machine.
We are not using calabash package dependency anywhere in our project.

While running my tests on App Center we are getting below error on App Center:

> SetUp : System.Exception : Failed to execute:
>   /Volumes/Data/xamarin/pipeline/versions/47ce72b23d7ff4d03244dfc4945dbf7b9c9d701a/adt/sdk/platform-tools/adb
>   shell am instrument -e "target_package" "com.hargray.MobileGuide" -e
>   "main_activity" "null" -e "debug" "false" -e "test_server_port"
>   "37777" -e "class"
>   "sh.calaba.instrumentationbackend.InstrumentationBackend"
>   com.hargray.MobileGuide.test/sh.calaba.instrumentationbackend.CalabashInstrumentationTestRunner
>   - exit code: 1/Volumes/Data/xamarin/pipeline/versions/47ce72b23d7ff4d03244dfc4945dbf7b9c9d701a/adt/sdk/platform-tools/adb:407:
>   warning: already initialized constant ARGVParse am instrument -e
>   target_package com.hargray.MobileGuide -e main_activity null -e debug
>   false -e test_server_port 37777 -e class
>   sh.calaba.instrumentationbackend.InstrumentationBackend
>   com.hargray.MobileGuide.test/sh.calaba.instrumentationbackend.CalabashInstrumentationTestRunner{:instrumentation=>"com.hargray.MobileGuide.test/sh.calaba.instrumentationbackend.CalabashInstrumentationTestRunner",
>   :instrumentation_name=>"sh.calaba.instrumentationbackend.CalabashInstrumentationTestRunner", :main_activity=>"null",
>   :class=>"sh.calaba.instrumentationbackend.InstrumentationBackend",
>   :target_package=>"com.hargray.MobileGuide",
>   :package_name=>"com.hargray.MobileGuide.test"}Parse am instrument -e
>   target_package com.hargray.MobileGuide -e main_activity null -e debug
>   false -e test_server_port 37777 -e class
>   sh.calaba.instrumentationbackend.InstrumentationBackend
>   com.hargray.MobileGuide.test/sh.calaba.instrumentationbackend.CalabashInstrumentationTestRunner{:instrumentation=>"com.hargray.MobileGuide.test/sh.calaba.instrumentationbackend.CalabashInstrumentationTestRunner",
>   :instrumentation_name=>"sh.calaba.instrumentationbackend.CalabashInstrumentationTestRunner", :main_activity=>"null",
>   :class=>"sh.calaba.instrumentationbackend.InstrumentationBackend",
>   :target_package=>"com.hargray.MobileGuide",
>   :package_name=>"com.hargray.MobileGuide.test"}/Volumes/Data/xamarin/pipeline/versions/47ce72b23d7ff4d03244dfc4945dbf7b9c9d701a/adt/sdk/platform-tools/adb:117:in
>   `shel': Error while starting {"message"=>"Waited for Calabash server
>   on 37282. Did not launch.",
>   "device_id"=>"e1569682-22a4-475c-b747-d45568eb827a",
>   "error_code"=>104}, 503, {"message":"Waited for Calabash server on
>   37282. Did not launch.","device_id":"e1569682-22a4-475c-b747-d45568eb827a","error_code":104}.
>   (RuntimeError)

Comment: Hi, I would thoroughly recommend contacting App Center support (the Intercom widget in the bottom right of the screen when you're logged in to App Center). To help get the support faster I would advise including the following information in your support request (don't put the link in here though): A link to an example test run with this error, the version of Android you're testing against and the information you've provided above.

Comment: The Calabash Android Server is added during a step on the server (it's also added locally when you run) but you don't have to do anything to include it on Android. It's the system that we use to interact with the app under test.

Comment: I would also advise trying the latest `-dev` nuget package of UITest just in case there's an issue that has been resolved recently.